# Find the UMVUE of $P(X \leq c)$ in exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, exponential-distribution

Given iid observations $X_1,...,X_n$ on X with the pdf $f_\theta (x)=e^{-(x-\theta)} I(x > \theta)$, find the UMVUE of $P(X \leq c)$, for fixed $c>0$.

My attempt:

I find $P(X \leq c)= 1-e^{-(c-\theta)}$

First, I find $T(X)=X_{(1)}$ is a complete and sufficient statistic for $\theta$. The any UMVUE should be based on $T(X)=X_{(1)}$.

I compute $E(T(X))=\frac{\theta n+1}{n}$. Thus, $T(X)=X_{(1)}$ is the UMVUE of  $\frac{\theta n+1}{n}$. Now there's still one step away. How to get the UMVUE of $1-e^{-(c-\theta)}$.

My idea is to compute $E[  1(X_1 \leq c)  |T]$. But I don't know how to compute that. Or there exists other ideas, such as some transformation of the density $X_{(1)}$ and we can get the expectation directly to the $e^{\theta}$.

Comment: Hint: find a complete and sufficient statistic (further hint: think about a specific order statistic) and find an unbiased functional of it after having found the distribution of your statistic.

Comment: @Snoop Thank you! I follow your hints. And now there's still one step away from the final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I follow [Shao's](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97553) approach with slight modifications and more details. We have $Y\sim e^{-(x-a)}\mathbf{1}_{(a,\infty)}(x)dx$ and $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ is an IID random sample from the law of $Y$. The minimum $X_{(1)}$ is a complete and sufficient statistic for $a$, so the UMVUE of $P(Y\leq c)$ for $c$ fixed will have the form $f(X_{(1)})$ and $E[f(X_{(1)})]=(1-e^{-(c-a)})\mathbf{1}_{(a,\infty)}(c)$. We can find for $t\geq a$:
$$P(X_{(1)}\geq t)=P(\cap_{k\leq n}\{X_k\geq t\})=e^{-n(t-a)}$$
and $1$ otherwise so $X_{(1)}\sim ne^{-n(x-a)}\mathbf{1}_{(a,\infty)}(x)dx$. So for $c> a$
$$E[f(X_{(1)})]=n\int_{(a,\infty)}f(x)e^{-n(x-a)}dx=1-e^{-(c-a)}$$
We solve the integral equation by differentiating wrt $a$:
$$-nf(a)+n\cdot \underbrace{n\int_{(a,\infty)}f(x)e^{-n(x-a)}dx}_{=1-e^{-(c-a)}}=-e^{-(c-a)}$$
so $f(a)=1-e^{-(c-a)}+n^{-1}e^{-(c-a)}=1-e^{-(c-a)}(1-n^{-1})$ and therefore
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1-e^{-(c-x)}(1-n^{-1})&c> x\\
0&c\leq x
\end{cases}$$
gives the UMVUE. Indeed, we can check again the calculations. We have for $c>a$:
$$\begin{aligned}E[f(X_{(1)})]&=n\int_{(a,\infty)}f(x)e^{-n(x-a)}dx\\
&=(1-e^{-n(c-a)})-(n-1)e^{na-c}\int_{(a,c)}e^{-x(n-1)}dx\\
&=1-e^{-(c-a)}\\
&=P(Y\leq c)
\end{aligned}$$
while for $c\leq a$: $E[f(X_{(1)})]=0=P(Y\leq c)$. So we conclude.

Comment: Can you explain how to get the derivative of $n\int_{(a,\infty)}f(x)e^{-n(x-a)}dx$?

Comment: @Jackie [have a look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: Can you help me this question? It's the same type. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808236/find-the-umvue-of-theta-from-zero-truncated-poisson-distribution

Comment: @Jackie I'll check it out!

Comment: Thank you so much!